# Conditional sorting in SSRS based on auto generated fields

Tags: sql, sorting, reporting-services

My question is this:

I have a report that populates its main fields from a Stored procedures that already has sort orders laid out for my report. 
 There is one row that I want to sort independently of the main report sorting. The values in this row are auto generated by another field in my report.
I need these values to appear according to the order of the other fields entry in the UI.

Does anyone know whether this has to be done in the proc or if I can sort this within the report?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a little more detail on what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree with DeadZone that more info is needed. I believe you will be able to sort the way you want by sorting on the table. Use the Sorting tab of the Table properties. Your expression will be something like 
`=IIF(Fields!SomeField.Value= "NormalSortType", Fields!YourSortField.Value, Fields!YourOtherSortField.Value)`
The first part will determine which are the records you want to sort normally, the second is the normal sort field, and the this part is your secondary sort field for the one you want to sort independently. If you want that one row to appear first, use 0 instead.

Comment: Can you put the special row in a different row group?